# Arduino BT upload problem

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I have an Arduino BT V06 that I could connect to my Mandriva 2010 linux laptop: "rfcomm connect" is working, /dev/rfcomm0 virtual serial port is created, "hcitool con" shows the connection and "hcidump" displays my upload attempts.
However when I try to upload the BlinkWithoutDelay example I got the following error message (upload.verbose set to true in .arduino/preferences.txt):

```
/usr/local/arduino-0021/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/local/arduino-0021/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega168 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/rfcomm0 -b19200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build8547029001705996442.tmp/BlinkWithoutDelay.cpp.hex:i

avrdude: Version 5.4-arduino, compiled on Oct 22 2007 at 13:15:12
        Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

        System wide configuration file is "/usr/local/arduino-0021/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
        User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
        User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

        Using Port            : /dev/rfcomm0
        Using Programmer      : stk500v1
        Overriding Baud Rate  : 19200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20]
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I was struggling for several hours to solve the problem.

I am using Arduino-0021 but I have also tried it in 0018 and 0015 without luck. I have also tried with board type BT Atmega 168 and BT Atmega 328. My Arduino Duemilanove works fine with the same computer, Arduino 0021, and settings.
I have seen several question with the same topic http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1290646119/1 or http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1247005623. They mention differing error messages and anyway I cannot see how can I press the reset button on the Arduino during the upload when I have to type the PIN in a different window.

**What could be the solution to the problem?**

What I could imagine is to buy a BlueGiga WT11 chip extension to my Duemilanove and do the upload via USB. But how could I be sure that the connection for the communication will work?
Moreover I still would like to use the not-so-cheap Arduino BT board.

**Update:**

Based on Nick T's answer I have tried again but the BT still does not work.
I have tried to press the reset button
- 3 seconds before,
- just before,
- at the same time of the upload button hit
and 
- when the first two/three avrdude lines appeared
- after the first two programmer is not responding lines appeared.

Altogether 20 times without success.

Even when the arduino environment has not been started and I press the reset button on the board the connection is lost (checked by hcitool con) after 1-4 presses.

**Are there any other ways to solve the problem?**

Do I have to buy a BlueGiga WT11 and hope that the bluetooth connection will work while the USB connection stays OK?

Comment: Did you find a solution, @rics?

Comment: Not yet, the board is not mine and now I cannot test it. I am thinking about buying a separate bluetooth module and connecting it to my Arduino Duemilanove board.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to bootload code on the Arduino, the programmer must attempt to connect within about 3 seconds of the AVR coming out of reset.  I the ArduinoBT I have *lacks* a connection that the traditional USB versions have, which allows the programming software to reset the Arduino by itself.  In lieu of that, you must physically hit the button to do it yourself.

> I cannot see how can I press the reset button on the Arduino during the upload when I have to type the PIN in a different window.

You should only have to type the Bluetooth passkey once, so after the BT module is paired with your computer, the computer should be able to freely connect, so long as it is powered.

The Bluetooth module and AVR are very separate; you can hold the AVR in reset, and the Bluetooth module will happily run along.  If you're *cutting power* to the entire board to reset it, it may indeed be difficult to have the BT module come online, connect to it, and initiate programming all within 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it did not work as I explained it in the update.

Comment: Can you connect to the BT module?  Hold the AVR in reset (keep button down or short it) and connect RX and TX together, open a terminal and it should echo everything you type.

Comment: You are right. I have connected RX and TX together started minicom, and found that keeping reset button down caused the echoing of the typed key. After reset connection was lost as yesterday. Does it mean that the BT connection is alive, doesn't it? What could I do next? Thx in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your problem might be in the AVR, either the chip is damaged, unprogrammed, or doesn't have the Arduino bootloader.  You would have to connect to it with an ISP to find out.  If you have an additional Arduino, you could put [ArduinoISP](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) on that and give it a whirl.

Comment: This board was working on an other machine, so it is programmed and at that time it was not damaged. There is a chance that we can try it tomorrow on that machine.

Comment: Unfortunately we could not test it, so I left the board at my colleague and he will continue the attempts for a while.